# OutBox pattern in MassTransit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit

My understanding is that the implementation of the OutBox pattern in MassTransit should save events when published to the bus. I am trying to add Entity framework Outbox in two services with my DB.

```
c.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<ProjectDbContext>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UsePostgres();
                cfg.UseBusOutbox();
            });
```

I need the OutBox pattern in case the bus is unavailable.
https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/middleware/outbox in the MassTransit documentation OutBox is added together with saga. When disabling RabbitMq to emulate a bus crash, no records of unpublished events appear in the database. How can I add OutBox to MassTransit without saga?

I added extensions to the database context and called the AddEntityFrameworkOutBox method when configuring MassTransit.

Comment: Hello have you tired the solution provided? Do you still need any further assistance on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Transactional Outbox uses the underlying database to store messages. However, the actual storage is controlled by your application. Ensure that you are calling `SaveChangesAsync` on the `DbContext` after your database operations are completed and any messages have been produced.

The [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox/blob/master/src/Sample.Components/RegistrationService.cs#L21) demonstrates this clearly, along with the accompanying [video](https://youtu.be/3TjGnmLno_A).